# Class variable not mutating in JS

Tags: javascript, class

I'm trying to build a simple JS snake game using classes. I've ran into a problem in which a variable declared in the constructor does not change. Here's my code:

```
class Snake {
  constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("graph");
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.snakeCoordinates = [{ x: 250, y: 250 }];
    this.dx = 10;
    this.dy = 0;

    this.drawSnake();
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.changeDirection());
  }


  changeDirection() {
    this.dx = -10;
  }
```

I added an event listener that calls my changeDirection function. However, when I console.log the dx variable, it remains unchanged.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.changeDirection());
```

doesn't do what you expect, you are *calling* the function here, just the first time, not passing it to `addEventListener`.

You would want to

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", this.changeDirection);
```

first, so that will be called on the keydown event instead, and finally just bind it:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", this.changeDirection.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! I just don't understand why binding it is necessary?

Comment: Binding is necessary because otherwise `this.dx` will not refer to the original instance of the class. If you pass `this.changeDirection`, you lose that context